# Where to Report Firmware issue?

Tags: bluetooth, firmware, bugs

I have a TP-Link UB500 Bluetooth 5 adapter which I use with a wireless keyboard and mouse on my Linux Mint machine. This adapter uses an RTL8761 chip.

After a recent update Linux mint version update I found that the connection to both the mouse and keyboard would drop frequently, typically every few minutes.

I managed to resolve the issue by installing the previous version of the firmware from `https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/firmware/`.

I would like to report this issue but where can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distributed firmware file was probably in a package named `firmware-realtek`, right?

Then run `apt info firmware-realtek | grep Maintainer` and you should see who/which group is responsible for maintaining that package, and usually also the email address to use for reporting a bug.

Comment: I think on my distro it's linux-firmware so I'll contact them

Comment: The maintainer’s email isn’t ever the right address to report a bug; the correct address is either the distribution’s bug tracker (*via* `reportbug` ideally on Debian derivatives) or the upstream maintainer or bug tracker.